# How do you make Media Source work with timestampOffset lower than appendWindowStart?

Tags: media-source

I want to use appendBuffer and append only piece of the media I have.
To cut the piece from the end, I use appendWindowEnd and it works.
To cut it from the beginning I have to set timestampOffset lower than appendWindowStart. I have seen shaka-player doing something similar.

```
var appendWindowStart = Math.max(0, currentPeriod.startTime - windowFudge);
var appendWindowEnd = followingPeriod ? followingPeriod.startTime : duration; 
...
var timestampOffset = currentPeriod.startTime -mediaState.stream.presentationTimeOffset;
```

From my tests, it works when timestampOffset is

- same as appendWindowStart
- 1/10 second lower

Does't work when timestampOffset is lower than that. The segment doesn't get added. Does that have something to do with my media or the spec/implementation doesn't allow it?

From MDN web docs:

> The appendWindowStart property of the SourceBuffer interface controls the timestamp for the start of the append window, a timestamp range that can be used to filter what media data is appended to the SourceBuffer. Coded media frames with timestamps within this range will be appended, whereas those outside the range will be filtered out.

Just found this in the specification, so I am updating the question:

> If presentation timestamp is less than appendWindowStart, then set the need random access point flag to true, drop the coded frame, and jump to the top of the loop to start processing the next coded frame.
>
> Some implementations may choose to collect some of these coded frames with presentation timestamp less than appendWindowStart and use them to generate a splice at the first coded frame that has a presentation timestamp greater than or equal to appendWindowStart even if that frame is not a random access point. Supporting this requires multiple decoders or faster than real-time decoding so for now this behavior will not be a normative requirement.
>
> If frame end timestamp is greater than appendWindowEnd, then set the need random access point flag to true, drop the coded frame, and jump to the top of the loop to start processing the next coded frame.
>
> Some implementations may choose to collect coded frames with presentation timestamp less than appendWindowEnd and frame end timestamp greater than appendWindowEnd and use them to generate a splice across the portion of the collected coded frames within the append window at time of collection, and the beginning portion of later processed frames which only partially overlap the end of the collected coded frames. Supporting this requires multiple decoders or faster than real-time decoding so for now this behavior will not be a normative requirement. In conjunction with collecting coded frames that span appendWindowStart, implementations may thus support gapless audio splicing.
>
> If the need random access point flag on track buffer equals true, then run the following steps:
> If the coded frame is not a random access point, then drop the coded frame and jump to the top of the loop to start processing the next coded frame.
> Set the need random access point flag on track buffer to false.

and

> Random Access Point
> A position in a media segment where decoding and continuous playback can begin without relying on any previous data in the segment. For video this tends to be the location of I-frames. In the case of audio, most audio frames can be treated as a random access point. Since video tracks tend to have a more sparse distribution of random access points, the location of these points are usually considered the random access points for multiplexed streams.

Does that mean, that for a video, I have to choose timeOffset, which lands on 'I' frame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of timestampOffset doesn't require an I-Frame. It just shifts the timestamp of each frame by that value. That shift calculations is performed before anything else (before appendWindowStart getting involved)

It's the use of appendWindowStart that are impacted to where your I-frames are.

appendWindowStart  and appendWindowEnd act as an *AND* over the data you're adding.

MSE doesn't reprocess your data, by setting appendWindowStart you're telling the source buffer that any data contained prior that time are to be excluded
Also MSE works at the fundamental level of GOP (group of picture): from one I-Frame to another.

So let's imagine this group of images, made of 16 frames GOP, each having a duration of 1s.

`.IPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP IPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP IPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP IPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP`

Say now you set appendWindowStart to 10
In the ideal world you would have:

`.         PPPPPPP IPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP IPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP IPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP`

All previous 9 frames with a time starting prior appendWindowStart have been dropped.

However, now those P-Frames can't be decoded, hence MSE set in the spec the "need random access point flag" to true, so the next frame added to the source buffer can only be an I-Frame
and so you end up in your source buffer with:

`.                 IPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP IPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP IPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP`

To be able to add the frames between appendWindowStart and the next I-Frame would be incredibly hard and time expensive.
It would require to decode all frames before adding them to the source buffer, storing them either as raw YUV data, or if hardware accelerated storing the GPU backed image.

A source buffer could contain over a minute of video at any given time. Imagine if it had to deal with decompressed data now rather than compressed one.

Now, if we wanted to preserve the same memory constraint as now (which is around 100MiB of data maximum per source buffer), you would have to recompress on the fly the content before adding it to the source buffer.

not gonna happen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I believe that the developers should choose (with some option) how they want appendWindowStart to work. In my case, I would like it to be able to work as a seek function and process the ~10 P frames following the I frame, so it can recreate the exact P frame I am looking for. The current hackish workaround to get the same functionality is a lot more resource-intensive. And yes, probably this is not a popularly requested feature, so I am not getting my hopes up